# MudNavMenu (MudBlazor) creates a mud-overlay when opened on Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, css, layout, mudblazor

I use a MudNavMenu of MudBlazor on the left side of the page.

It worked fine with Chrome. However, on Edge with a small screen, an overlay appears on the screen when I open the menu/drawer. This does not happen on Chrome. I am not sure whether it is a problem with Edge or MudBlazor. How to remove this on Edge?
[image]

Comment: share your code